# Model ensemble with caretStack

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, ensemble-learning

I'm building a model ensemble with *caretStack* (package *caretEnsemble*).
Here is a basic example :

```
library(caret);library(caretEnsemble)
models <- caretList(
    x=iris[1:100,1:2],
    y=iris[1:100,3],
    trControl=trainControl(method="cv"),
    methodList=c("lm","rpart", "glm")
)
meta_model <- caretStack(models, method="rf")
```

First, I would like a confirmation that I understand how this function works.
Correct me if I am wrong :

- caretList uses *lm*,*rpart* and *glm* to fit x1 and x2 to y (i.e., *y~x1+x2*)
- This gives three predictions : *plm*, *prpart*, *pglm*
- Then caretStack creates the model ensemble and provides a global prediction with *rf* such as *y~plm+prpart+pglm*

Second, I think that, depending of the predictor values, one model or another will work better, thus I would like that caretStack takes into account the *x1* and *x2* predictors *y~plm+prpart+pglm+x1+x2*

Thus, is it possible to include predictors (eg x1, x2 in my example) in the caretStack ensemble modeling ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "do this"?

Comment: @whuber done, is it clearer like this ?